# Run job to check if mail is sent or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob

I am sending mail through sidekiq.

Now I have to run a job which will check if the mail is sent or not, because I have to call a method on successful mail send . Is there any method to do this in rails?

Comment: Why an extra job monitoring another job. Your sidekiq worker could just mark the mail as successfully send in the database.

Comment: Which mail service are you using: sendgrid, mailchimp,..?

Comment: I am just using letter opener which send mail locally to my browser. @HieuPham

Comment: @spickermann Because I have to call a method as the mail is sent

Comment: Is it possible that the sidekiq worker calls that method after it successfully sent the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save this adding a new attribute in a table if the email was sent successfully

```
if UserMailer.delay.application_rejected(user)
  user.update_column(:email_status_rejected, true) # the email was sent to the job
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq [does not allow to check status of a particular job](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/536#issuecomment-18439408). That is what **Batches** are for.

Refer to this [documentation of Batches](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches).
They provide detailed information in case of failures and also have neat callback methods which you can use.

**Edit:** If you just want to monitor your jobs, sidekiq provides a nice web interface for that: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#web-ui